# Why dlib facial landmark detector throws RuntimeError?

Tags: python, opencv, dlib

I am quite new at python programming. I am trying to run the sample code for dlib facial landmark detector. Unfortunately I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "facial_landmarks.py", line 109, in <module>
    predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(predictor_path)
RuntimeError: Error deserializing object of type long
   while deserializing a dlib::matrix
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: It's pretty hard to look at the error only. Why don't you post the relevant code?

Comment: Did you unzip the model file it's trying to load?

Answer (score 2):

The shape predictor for dlib is missing:

1. Download and extract the model for shape predicting (about 60 MB):

   ```
   wget http://dlib.net/files/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2
   bzip2 -dk shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2
   ```
2. The pass the the predictor file path as first argument to your Python script:

   ```
   python facial_landmarks.py shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat faces/*.jpg
   ```

A great walkthrough, on how to use dlib for facial landmark detection can be found here: http://www.learnopencv.com/facial-landmark-detection/

Answer (score 1):

This message will be caused by one of the following:

- The file pointed to by predictor_path is corrupt or missing
- You've forgotten to unzip the file pointed to by predictor_path
- Some other issue with the underlying file system not delivering the data correctly to dlib.shape_predictor (e.g. disk corruption, file permissions, symbolic link problem)

Take a more detailed look at the dlib example itself:
http://dlib.net/face_landmark_detection.py.html